# Software to design villages with orthographic view

Tags: cities, software-recommendations, simulated-worlds

Is there a software solution or technique for making static 3D images of a realistic looking village? I am hoping for an orthographic view. I know there is the new [Cities: Skyline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities:_Skylines), but it makes cities, not villages.

Comment: I was considering my answer as only temporary. Did it answer your question ?

Comment: @Vincent I have not tried it yet. I am hoping for additional opinions. I am doing my own research into methods as well, but it may take a week or so before I understand the options better.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Banished](http://www.shiningrocksoftware.com/game/) for a medieval realistic setting. Some people find it hard but once you get the hang of it, it's not so bad. You can also download mods via the Workshop if your on Steam. There is another community on the official website I believe but the Steam community is much more active.

I can also tell you how to make isometric maps using photoshop and/or illustrator. http://torstan.deviantart.com/art/How-to-draw-isometric-dungeon-plans-278860194

Comment: +1 On Banished, I thought of the same right away at the mention of villages. I believe banished also has a map editor so you can probably skip the trouble of playing the game to get the village you want (which you may find excruciatingly hard at start)